# Make a json for grid data and send to back end

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

I need to make a json string for grid table field list.and need to send them java back end.

I have to send

```
id,
name,
listOfProjects,
```

listOfProjects contains following list,this list may contains number of items.

```
prjId,
prjName
```

Please tell me how to create a json string ?

I tried with following code sample

`var dataStr = new Object();`

`dataStr.id=myId;`

`dataStr.name="myName";`

`dataStr.plist = new Array();`

```
dataStr.plist[0].prjId=1stId;
dataStr.plist[0].prjName="1stName";

dataStr.plist[1].prjId=2ndId;
dataStr.plist[1].prjName="2ndName";

dataStr.plist[2].prjId=3rdId;
dataStr.plist[2].prjName="3rdName";
```

`var data = Ext.JSON.encode(dataStr);`

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url : '/E2EAT/authentication/userdetails.json',
    method : "GET",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    params : 'data=' +  data ,
    useDefaultXhrHeader : false,
    withCredentials: true,
});
```

I can use the code above, but I need to iterate grid

1 . Please let me know how can I iterate a grid with sencha?

2 . What's the best method to make json string and send back end?

Comment: Are you trying to say that,you want to get the data from the grid and send it to the server.

Comment: If so,can you please post your store info(mean to say your data format in store,so that it would be more clear).

Answer (score 1):

Ext gives you two loop functions: [`Ext.each`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext-method-each), and [`Ext.iterate`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext-method-iterate) for objects.

To iterate over columns of a grid, you can use the [`Ext.grid.Panel#columns`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-columns) array property, containing [`Columns`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column) instances. For example, in order to build a list of visible columns, you can do:

```
var visibleColumns = [];
Ext.each(grid.columns, function(column) {
    // Only columns bound to a field (exludes actions colutions, etc.)
    if (!Ext.isEmpty(column.dataIndex)) {
        if (column.isVisible()) {
            visibleColumns.push({
                field: column.dataIndex
                ,label: column.text
            });
        }
    }
});
```

A grid doesn't necessarily have a column for every field of the underlying store, and it can have extra columns for custom rendering, actions, numbering, selection, etc. So, you may want to iterate over the fields of the store, instead of the grid columns. In this case, we'd be working we've [`Ext.data.Field`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Field) objects:

```
// Get a ref to the store's model. Stores always have models; even
// if none is specified explicitly, one is created implicitly.
var model = grid.getStore().model;

var fieldNames = [];
Ext.each(model.getFields(), function(field) {
    fieldNames.push(field.name);
});
```

Finally, you turn your data into JSON using [`Ext.encode`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext-method-encode). Also, you don't have to build the URL query (params) yourself, which would give more flexibility to other parts of your code that may need to add some params:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    ...
    params: {
        data: Ext.encode(rawData)
    }
});
```

For a POST request, you can also use the [`jsonData`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Connection-method-request) property, to save yourself the json encoding:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    ...
    jsonData: {
        data: rawData
    }
});
```

In many cases, though, it will be preferable to use a store with an appropriately configured [data proxy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Proxy) and [writer](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.writer.Writer) rather than a direct AJAX request.